# What is the status of SpatiaLite in 2024?

Tags: spatialite

I'm trying to figure out the feasibility of using SpatiaLite in a project.

The [official website](https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/index) seems to be pretty old and without obvious instructions for how to install it - although the latest release is August 2023.

So I'm looking for information about the current status of the project and if there are friendlier ways to install and use it.

Comment: Although a bit dated now, I think it is still worth reading [What happened to SpatiaLite during last years](https://groups.google.com/g/spatialite-users/c/vKLokX4aSVU/m/qNDZDBoSAwAJ) since the thoughts are straight from the source.

Answer (score 1):

Your intentions on how to use Spatialite are vague, so my answer is my personal experience for various points of view.

### Create a Spatialite database

Since I use QGIS as the front-end GIS platform, the easy way to create a Spatialite database is via QGIS *Layer -> Create Layer -> New SpatiaLite Layer...*. This will create an SQLite database along with all tables and fuctions to operate on geometry data.

Another option could be the spatialite-gui but I have not tried it.

### Administer and Operate the database

You need to check if your favorite tools support SpatiaLite. For example, DBeaver has limited support. The only tool I have found that is best suited is DB Browser for SQLite. At least, it presents the geometry data in WKT format. It may be a bit tricky to load the extension (mod_spatialite.dll in Windows). Since there are several versions of the .dll, the one that worked for me was the one packaged with QGIS. Very important is to add to the PATH the location of the dll, then load the extension and finally make it persistent. This information was gathered in various online posts.

### Application development

You need to check if your favorite programming language plus the database access work with Spatialite. I work with PHP, having PDO as the database access layer. I was surprised to find out that I could not use PDO, because the developers of drivers are having disputes regarding security issues on loading extensions. This is one line of code to fix, but you need to recompile the PDO drivers for your environment. For me it was a no-go.

### Function compatibility with PostGis

There are differences on the naming and usage of functions comparing to PostGis. For example, *MakePoint( x Double precision , y Double precision , [ , SRID Integer] ) : Geometry*     of Spatialite is *ST_MakePoint(float x, float y)* in PostGis. The differences are not so big, but from a programmer's point of view, you need to create a separate set of commands depending on the database you use. And also spend time to locate such differences via trial and error.

In conclusion, PostgreSQL/PostGis would be my number one choice, even for very small projects running on your personal computer. Perhaps SpatiaLite could be used for embedded applications, if you want to develop some specialized software and you want a database of low installation and packaging cost.

Answer (score 0):

The SpatiaLite code is more usable than the web site, fortunately.

The timeline view https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/timeline in the source code repository shows pretty well what has been happening lately. The issue ticket list is at https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/rptview?rn=1 may tell if there are critical bugs. And you can always read the old postings from the user forum or write and ask yourself. The forum is at https://groups.google.com/g/spatialite-users.

There are makefiles and build instructions at https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/tree?type=flat

I believe that most GDAL distributions are built with SpatiaLite support and you can access the SpatiaLite SQL functions https://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-5.1.0.html through GDAL by using the SQLite SQL dialect https://gdal.org/user/sql_sqlite_dialect.html.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you are refering to the spatialite "file format" or only to the library or both. For information: for the vast majority of functionalities the spatialite library also supports Geopackage files, which is an OGC standard and a quite popular format.

I use the spatialite library a lot for the development of a python library, [geofileops](https://geofileops.readthedocs.io), and I've been quite happy with it. Updates are a bit slow to be released, but if you have questions the response time on the user forum is typically quite ok: [spatialite-users](https://groups.google.com/g/spatialite-users)

For installation, I typically use the [libspatialite](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/libspatialite) conda package, but spatialite is also packaged with [GDAL](https://gdal.org).